# Query to return time difference between events, grouped by id

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in mysql that i am trying to query on

```
id    |  type  |                  dt | seqid
--------------------------------------------
1001  |  login | 2017-07-11 01:52:39 | 1
1001  | change | 2017-07-11 01:53:07 | 2
1001  | logout | 2017-07-11 01:53:21 | 3
1002  |  login | 2017-07-11 14:08:20 | 1
1002  | logout | 2017-07-11 14:08:28 | 2
--------------------------------------------
```

I essentially need to display the time difference between each event(type) grouped on the basis of id. the output should be something on the lines of

```
1001 | Login | 0   (0 calculated since login is the starting event)
1001 | change | 28 (difference between login and this event)
---------------------
```

and so on.

I have written the following query

```
SELECT 
    curr.id, 
    curr.type, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,curr.dt , prev.dt) as diff 
FROM 
    sys.rep AS curr 
LEFT JOIN sys.rep AS prev ON prev.seqid = (
    SELECT min(seqid) 
    FROM sys.rep WHERE  seqid > curr.seqid and id = curr.id
);
```

The query works fine for one id but fails for multiple ids. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @AlexTartan

Comment: Seqid serves no useful purpose, right?

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
SELECT a.*
     , timediff(b.dt,a.dt) diff
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.dt) next
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.id = x.id
          AND y.dt > x.dt
        GROUP
           BY x.id
     ) a
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.id = a.id
   AND b.dt = a.next;
```

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry